# Replace std.error of OLS by HAC estimator, and use stargazer to print table

Tags: r, stargazer

It is my first time posting questions here.

I'm dealing with a case where I use time series data to do simple ols estimate, by using *dynlm*. Also, I want to replace the standard error by HAC estimator with some conventional truncated value as the lag variable. The code is like what follows:

```
dat <- ts(data)
reg <- dynlm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat)
ols <- summary(reg)
robust <- coeftest(reg, vcov=NeweyWest(reg, lag = round(0.75 * length(time(reg))^(1/3))))
ols$coefficients[,2:4] <- robust[,2:4]
ols
```

I use the same method over 16 data sets, and now I want to print the results into a latex table by using *stargazer*. However, the package can only generate tables by the results of a linear model rather than its summary (take the preceding code as an example, *stargazer* can be applied to **reg** rather than **ols**), which I already know.

It seems to me that there are two ways to deal with it

1. Find a way to generate latex tables by using summaries of regressions.
2. Replace the std errors, t stats and p-values in **reg** rather than those in **summary(reg)**.

It would be so nice of you to give me an aid! Thanks!

Comment: The way I deal with it right now is to print tables with original OLS results, and then key in HAC standard error MANUALLY, which is really stupid.

Comment: welcome to SO!  Just to clarify, when you mention to print the results to latex table, is the output a part of dissertation or just a n one-off print in R console? Also, a sample data would be helpful for people to answer as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use the arguments **se** and **t** in *stargazer* to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu it's just an one-off print in R console. I want to use an open data set to be more specific as well...I'll try to do so later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly, but if I do the answer is quite easy and has been provided in this thread: [Extending Stargazer to multiwaycov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458574/extending-stargazer-to-multiwaycov/45433861#45433861)

You simply have to supply the robust standard errors and p-values to the stargazer function directly with

```
stargazer(ols, ..., se = robust[,2], p = robust[,4], p.auto = F)
```

No need to supply t-statistics as they are calculated by stargazer based on the supplied std. errors and coefficients.

I would strongly suggest to read the stargazer documentation and search SO more carefully before posting a question.

Comment: I end up writing a function to generate the HAC standard error estimator and then put them into _stargazer_ with `se = c(list(HAC1), list(HAC2),...)`, and it works well. Below are the links and discussion that gave me adequate help.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048097/r-robust-ses-and-model-diagnostics-in-stargazer-table]